# Angular with express ejs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, css, angular-ui-router

I am having a problem getting my partials to show inside my index.html
this is a view of my file tree:

[tree structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2B2O.png)

and my index page looks like this
[index.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQhPu.png)

So I am not sure what else you might need to see I know the routes are working because I checked with ARC (chrome app) So, if there is anything else you need to better help you then just let me know and I will glady get it for you. My question is is that not how you do (or can do) partials with angular

beeperApp.js file

```
var app = angular.module('beeperApp', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
    //the timeline display
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'main.html',
            controller: 'mainController'
        })
        //the login display
        .when('/login', {
            templateUrl: 'login.html',
            controller: 'authController'
        })
        //the signup display
        .when('/register', {
            templateUrl: 'register.html',
            controller: 'authController'
        });
});

app.controller('mainController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.posts = [];
    $scope.newPost = {created_by: '', text: '', created_at: ''};

    $scope.post = function () {
        //Add a created at (time and date) for a new post
        $scope.newPost.created_at = Date.now();

        //Take whatever was created in new post and add that to the post message
        $scope.posts.push($scope.newPost);

        //Reset the new post to empty
        $scope.newPost = {created_by: '', text: '', created_at: ''};
    };
});

app.controller('authController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.user = {username: '', email: '', password: ''};
    $scope.error_message = '';

    $scope.login = function () {
        //authentication
        $scope.error_message = 'login request for ' + $scope.user.username;
    };

    $scope.register = function () {
        //authentication
        $scope.error_message = 'register request for ' + $scope.user.username;
    };
});

app.controller('loginController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.user = {username: '', password: ''};
    $scope.error_message = '';

    $scope.login = function () {
        //authentication
        $scope.error_message = 'login request for ' + $scope.user.username;
    };
});
```

Comment: can you show your controller?

Comment: Please show your `beeperApp.js` file.

Comment: When I load the page and enter the developer tools and hover over different areas it is showing that something is supposed to be there but nothing shows up.

Comment: I am not sure what exactly is the question you are asking  ? please be a bit more specific and try to use better language

Comment: Ok... So, I am trying to get the main.html login.html and register.html to show up on the index.html page.And I was following a video tutorial on how to do this but nothing is working. When I re-watch the video I don't see anything different that I am doing that they did not do. So, I am really just asking if there is anything that I am missing or with what I have here should it work. I see the terminal say that it is requesting the proper pages on page load but it doesn't show anything.